# How to create a menu which slides from left

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I want to create a responsive navigation menu which slides from left when button is pushed. Which is the the simplest way to do this?

It's no problem if it's jquery or CSS3-transitions, it doesn't matter.

I've searched on the net but didn't find some good tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good demo / tutorial:

http://callmenick.com/post/slide-and-push-menus-with-css3-transitions

It's not simple but it will be a great education to go over all that code.

Comment: Thank you!! That's a good tutorial which include slide-in from the other positions :)